# Why are Django REST API decorators breaking the Django non_atomic_requests decorator?

Tags: django, python-2.7, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I have a Python Django REST API view like this:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from django.db import transaction

@api_view( [ 'POST' ] )
@permission_classes( ( IsAuthenticated, ) )
@transaction.non_atomic_requests
def myview( request ):
    with transaction.atomic():
        db_do_something1()

    with transaction.atomic():
        do_do_something2()

    return some_response
```

The SQL actually run against my PostgreSQL database in this case creates savepoints before and after `db_do_something1` and `2` - but critically **does not commit** after leaving the with blocks.

The entire view is still wrapped within a `BEING` and `COMMIT` is only issued to the database at the end of the view.

If I move the `@transaction.non_atomic_requests` decorator to the beginning of the decorator list, then I get the correct behavior, with each `with` block being in its own transaction and committing at the end.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`api_view` creates an APIView behind the scene.
Depending on where the `transaction.non_atomic_requests` is called, it might be added to the wrong function (such as the `as_view` instead of `myview`.

The documentation may need an update to put some emphasis on it. I don't remember that was reported already.